# Docker networking not working with eureka

Tags: spring, docker, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have one eureka server inside a docker container and another application inside another docker container. I have made a network using `docker network create eureka-s1`. So, I'm running the eureka server using the command: `docker run --network eureka-s1 --name eureka-server -p 8761:8761 f595acb214d5`
The config file of the eureka server is as follows:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-service

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address:true
    hostname:localhost

  client:
    eureka-server-connect-timeout-seconds: 5
    enabled: true
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false

server:
  port: 8761
```

So, its running fine. Now, when I run my application using the command: `docker run --network eureka-s1 --name first-service -p 8080:8080 c16b2442b890`, the application is not registering to eureka. The config file of the client is as follows:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: first-service
server:
  port: 8080
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
```

Can someone point out the problem here? Thanks.

Edit:
 Eureka Server Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/cloud-eureka-discovery-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar cloud-eureka-discovery-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8761
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "cloud-eureka-discovery-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Eureka Client Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/first-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar first-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "first-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Comment: From application's container can you ping eureka server?

Comment: Yes, here are the statistics:  --- eureka-server ping statistics ---
39 packets transmitted, 39 received, 0% packet loss, time 962ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.048/0.113/0.207/0.049 ms

Comment: Then I guess the problem lies on your eureka server configuration. I would make some attempts with `hostname:localhost`. You could change it to eureka-server instead of localhost or remove it if it not mandatory. Search spring's eureka docs for possible alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's work fine with docker-compose.

Below is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  eureka:
    build: ${PATH_TO_EUREKA_FOLDER}
    mem_limit: 350m
    networks:
        - my-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://eureka:8761"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  client:
    build: ${PATH_TO_YOUR_CLIENT_FOLDER}
    mem_limit: 350m
    networks:
      - my-network
    links:
      - eureka
    depends_on:
      eureka:
        condition: service_healthy


networks:
  my-network:
    name: my-network
```

And add update your client config file as bellow :

```
spring:
    application:
        name: first-service
server:
    port: 8080
eureka:
    client:
        fetch-registry: true
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://eureka:8761/eureka
```

And update the Dockerfile of the eureka server as bellow :

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl

EXPOSE 8761

ADD ./target/*.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

And next to docker-compose.yml run

```
docker-compose up --build
```

And don't forget to run mvn clean install your client application.

Comment: Didn't work. Any other suggestions? I can try to register on the mapped port on the machine also, instead of the container. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: can you post both Dockerfile ?

Comment: Can you tell me what went wrong with docker run and why this solution worked?

Comment: I suspect that your eureka was not exposed in the same network, with docker-compose we specified the same network for both the client and eureka app.